# Installing virtual environment kernel for jupyter notebook throws "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, jupyter-kernel

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 lts

I have created a virtual environment "analytics-3" using virtualenvironmentwrapper and felt the need to use Jupyter notebook for some work.

Python version :- 3.5.2

Downloaded Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh and installed anaconda outside of the virtual environment.

"jupyter notebook" is running perfectly.

I want to make a kernel for this specific "analytics-3" virtual environment and followed the steps :-

1)activated analytics-3 (using workon)

2)Installed ipykernel inside it

3)Tried to install the kernel in jupyter notebook  using :-

python -m ipykernel install --user --name analytics-3 --display-name "xyz"

Getting this error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/home/odin/.virtualenvs/analytics-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
      File "/home/odin/.virtualenvs/analytics-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 15, in <module>
        from tornado import ioloop
      File "/home/odin/.virtualenvs/analytics-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 45, in <module>
        from tornado.concurrent import (
      File "/home/odin/.virtualenvs/analytics-3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 175, in <module>
        future: Union["futures.Future[_T]", "Future[_T]"], value: _T
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
        dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
        for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
        for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
        self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
        eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

A simple google search throws no light.Please guide me how to resolve this.

Comment: I got around by updating the existing python version from 3.5.2 to 3.6.3 and installing  a compatible anaconda installation.
If this helps.Thanks.

@phd, Jean-François Fabre ,before asking this question, I have already tried implementing the solution "update tornado" from the potential duplicate question with no success.